# Get destination addres for UDP in nodejs

Tags: node.js, networking, udp

My server listens on a UDP port and also receives broadcast messages. Can I detect somehow if the received message was sent to my ip directly or to a broadcast address? `rinfo` just gives me the sender information

Comment: I did UDP stuff, but never done broadcast stuff, so this is simply my impression. If you find there is no way to do that in the end, I would recommend you to have separate receivers for each of direct and broadcast messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible.

[See this Github bug link](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6589)

Workaround:

- have different internal ports for the broadcast and the normal traffic.
- Use iptables to redirect broadcast traffic to one of the internal port and the other traffic to the other port.